# Creating multiplatform NuGet packet

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmake, nuget

I would like to provide a C# wrapper for my shared library written in C.

- C library is just a simplified abstraction over
  [Windows Filtering Platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fwp/about-windows-filtering-platform).
- Main project is written in C# and is compiled for `AnyCPU` platform target.
- I use [CMake](https://cmake.org/) for C and C# wrapper project generation.

For the C# wrapper to be able to work properly on both `x64` and `x86` platforms
I have to load C shared library at runtime depending on the user's platform.

```
             +------------------+
             |csharp_wrapper.dll|
             +----+---------+---+
                  |         |
             x86? |         | x64?
          +-------+         +------+
          |                        |
          v                        v
+---------+-------+       +--------+--------+
|x86/c_library.dll|       |x64/c_library.dll|
+-----------------+       +-----------------+
```

I've read that [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) is a popular way in C# to ship reusable
class libraries.

I have no prior knowledge working with Visual Studio and how build configuration is normally
done.

I would like to have a "single click" build process to build
C# wrapper and C libraries for x86 and x64 architectures so that I could make
NuGet packet.

Is there a way in `Visual Studio` or a `CMake` to build for x64 and x86 architectures
without writing custom `batch` script to build x86 and x64 separately?

I have little knowledge working with Microsoft Windows and Visual Studio so any
help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking what you have to click in Visual Studio to change between x86 and x64? Or are you asking how to create a build script without writing a script?